# computing stable manifold for non homogeneous linear ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

Consider the system of ODEs

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -2x -y +1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} =  -y $$

The eigenvalues of the corresponding derivative are $-2$ and $-1$ with eigenvectors $e_1$ and $e_2$ respectively. There are two stable manifolds corresponding to the fixed point $(0.5,0)$, the strong one $U_{SS}$ orthogonal to $e_1$ and the weak one $U_{WS}$ orthogonal to $e_2$. I also know that an initial condition picked on $U_{SS}$ will stay on $U_{SS}$ with the fastest contraction rate, by the stable manifold theorem.

But how exactly do I get the graph of $U_{SS}$? In the figure of the linear ode simulated below, we see the density along where the stable manifold should be. Is this curve the global stable manifold?

[image]

Comment: In linear ODEs, the stable manifold is the stable eigenspace. The eigenspaces related to $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the eigenvectors related to $e_1$ and $e_2$, respectively. The whole space $R^2$ is also $E^s=W^s$ (the stable eigenspace or the stable manifold).

Comment: @khashayar Yes the whole space correponds the entire stable manifold, but what is the "stronger one" corresponding to only $e_1$?

Comment: It looks cubic.

Comment: Any curve of the form $y^2=C\big(x+y-\frac{1}{2}\big)$ will be an invariant manifold of your DE. Here, $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Any such invariant will pass through $(0.5,0)$.

Comment: @MatthewH. Put that as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linear ODEs, the stable manifold is the stable eigenspace. The eigenspaces related to $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the eigenvectors related to $e_1$ and $e_2$, respectively. The whole space $R^2$ is also $E^s=W^s$ (the stable eigenspace or the stable manifold).

The eigenvector related to $e_1$ is $[1 \ 0]^T$ because $\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}=-2\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}$ implies that $v_2=0$.

Now the fact that $[1 \ 0]^T$ is the eignevector of $e_1$ implies that $U_{ss}$ is the x-axis or $y=0$